# Why does data.table update names(DT) by reference, even if I assign to another variable?

Tags: r, data.table

I've stored the names of a `data.table` as a `vector`:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(x = runif(100), y = runif(100))
names1 <- names(DT)
```

As far as I can tell, it's a plain vanilla character vector:

```
str(names1)
# chr [1:2] "x" "y"

class(names1)
# [1] "character"

dput(names1)
# c("x", "y")
```

However, this is no ordinary character vector. It's a magic character vector!  When I add a new column to my `data.table`, this vector gets updated!

```
DT[ , z := runif(100)]
names1
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
```

I know this has something to do with how `:=` updates by assignment, but this still seems magic to me, as I expect `<-` to make a *copy* of the `data.table`'s names.

I can fix this by wrapping the names in `c()`:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(x = runif(100), y = runif(100))

names1 <- names(DT)
names2 <- c(names(DT))
all.equal(names1, names2)
# [1] TRUE

DT[ , z := runif(100)]
names1
# [1] "x" "y" "z"

names2
# [1] "x" "y"
```

My question is 2-fold:

1. Why doesn't `names1 <- names(DT)` create a copy of the `data.table`'s names?  In other instances, we are explicitly warned that `<-` creates copies, both of `data.table`s and `data.frame`s.
2. What's the difference between `names1 <- names(DT)` and `names2 <- c(names(DT))`?

Comment: Great question! Following up on Arun's answer, I've filed [#2675](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2675&group_id=240&atid=975) to document that `nm <- copy(names(DT))` is needed. Thanks for highlighting, I didn't realise this before.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

#### Update: This is now added in the documentation for `?copy` in version 1.9.3. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> 14. Moved `?copy` to it's own help page, and documented that `dt_names <- copy(names(DT))` is necessary for `dt_names` to be not modified by reference as a result of updating `DT` by reference (ex: adding a new column by reference). Closes [#512](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/512). Thanks to Zach for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15913417/559784) and user1971988 for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18662715/559784).

---

Part of your first question makes it a bit unclear *to me* as to what you really mean about `<-` operator (at least in the context of `data.table`), especially the part: *In other instances, we are explicitly warned that <- creates copies, both of data.tables and data.frames.*

So, before answering your actual question, I'll briefly touch it here. In case of a `data.table` a `<-` (assignment) merely is *not sufficient* for copying a `data.table`. For example:

```
DT <- data.table(x = 1:5, y= 6:10)
# assign DT2 to DT
DT2 <- DT # assign by reference, no copy taken.
DT2[, z := 11:15]
# DT will also have the z column
```

If you want to create a `copy`, then you've to explicitly mention it using `copy` command.

```
DT2 <- copy(DT) # copied content to DT2
DT2[, z := 11:15] # only DT2 is affected
```

From CauchyDistributedRV, I understand what you mean is the assignment `names(dt) <- .` that'll result in the warning. I'll leave it as such.

---

**Now, to answer your first question:** It seems that `names1 <- names(DT)` also behaves similarly. I hadn't thought/known about this until now. The `.Internal(inspect(.))` command is very useful here:

```
.Internal(inspect(names1))
# @7fc86a851480 16 STRSXP g0c7 [MARK,NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=100)
#   @7fc86a069f68 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "x"
#   @7fc86a0f96d8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "y"

.Internal(inspect(names(DT)))
# @7fc86a851480 16 STRSXP g0c7 [MARK,NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=100)
#   @7fc86a069f68 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "x"
#   @7fc86a0f96d8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "y"
```

Here, you see that they are pointing to the same memory location `@7fc86a851480`. Even the `truelength` of `names1` is 100 (which is by default allocated in `data.table`, check `?alloc.col` for this).

```
truelength(names1)
# [1] 100
```

So basically, the assignment `names1 <- names(dt)` seems to happen by reference. That is, `names1` is pointing to the same location as dt's column names pointer.

**To answer your second question:** The command `c(.)` seems to create a copy *as there is no checking as to whether the contents result due to concatenation operation are different*. That is, because `c(.)` operation can change the contents of the vector, it immediately results in a "copy" being made *without* checking if the contents are modified are not.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was starting to get there myself, as I had just discovered `.Internal(inspect())`.  I guess I hadn't realized that basic *vectors* could actually internally be a reference to a `data.table`-- I had always thought that only a `data.table` could internally be a reference to a `data.table`.

Comment: This is interesting. I wonder what's going on under the hood to force `names` not to copy the vector on assignment? Also, I imagine the confusion arose because `names<-.data.table` does force a copy, hence the `setnames` function. My guess: it has to do with how `data.table` plays with reference counting.

Comment: This is news to me too, great question. The names vector is over-allocated as well as the vector of column pointers. When `:=` assigns a new column it also updated the names vector by reference, too. This could be changed/fixed by not making the names vector over-allocated.  But then it would be a little slower if adding columns in a loop. So perhaps better to document that `nm <- copy(names(DT))` is needed, otherwise `names(DT)` returns a reference.

Comment: ahhh, Arun, this is the comment you were referring to! (Thanks @statquant for the link).     Matthew, I agree that the documentation should emphasize using `copy` whenever a copy is expected to be a replica.  As for the source of the issue, I'm pretty certain it's due to the lazy evaluation of `<-`.   See this (duplicate!) post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16543387/1492421