# update a data frame and environment in R

Tags: r, scoping

I am not quite sure why the data frame object does not update

```
d <- data.frame(titi=c(0))
(function(dataset) {
  dataset[["toto"]] <- 1;
  print(names(dataset)) #has "toto" and "titi"
})(d)
print(names(d)) # no has "toto", only "titi"
```

What is going on here ?

I have a workaround as in my code I also capture the variable and update the captured with `<<-`, but I'd like to know the mechanism.

I am aware of the danger of mutation in general etc.. I just dont understand the mechanism at play here.

**Edit**

Although it seems to be the consensus that this is a language level feature, I dont follow the argument, as if I use a close structure, the data table, it **can** mutate :

```
d <- data.table(titi=c(0))
(function(dataset) {
  dataset[,toto:=1]
  print(names(dataset)) #"titi" "toto"
})(d)
print(names(d)) #"titi" "toto"
```

Comment: Functions in R do NOT alter data "in-place" or "by-reference". If you wanted that function to alter "d" then you would need to assign its output to "d". Using `<<-` to get around this design of R is considered dangerous and ugly.

Comment: so depending on whether I an inside a function or not, my *instruction* has a different meaning ?

Comment: Your function made a copy of `d` (named `dataset`), added the new column, then discarded the results. As @Dwin noted, you would need to assign the function output.

Comment: Define "meaning", please. It has a different environment, same local "meaning".

Comment: It has nothing to do with "data.frame objects" per se and everything to do with where changes are being made. The copy of "d" was altered, and if you had assigned its result to the object name "d" using `d <- function(.) {....}` , then success.

Comment: @bdemarest of course that is it. I dont know why I was under the impression data.frame were handed over by ref (is it the case in data.table ?). semantically they are copied (although inspection of memory shows this is optimized, and copy happens only upon mutation, which can be seen with .Internal(inspect(dataset)))

Comment: sorry that is just not true. they are passed by ref.

Comment: @DWin In my current understanding, I actually think it has **everything** to do with data.frame objects.

Comment: @DWin if the object of the mutation, obtained through <<-, is well localized (which in my case can only happen in 1 place, the closed over variable), there is nothing dirty at all.

Comment: 'data.frame' objects are just a form of list. There is nothing about the use of `<<-` within a function that is specific to lists with a class of 'data.frame`. `data.table` objects are different by design and most of R objects and R functions are not like 'data.table' objects or functions.

Comment: Question is good, I don't understand the downvotes. The underlying feature here are `environment`s, which can be updated in-place (by reference). It's this basic structure that allows the implementation of `data.table` and other unusual objects that can be altered as side-effects of any function. I believe you'll enjoy this: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft.I would think the down votes flow from the comments. The inferno is a great reference here.

Comment: @DWin you are right, this is also the case with the list implementation.

Comment: @mnel it would be good for R if the half baked principles were looked at honestly and not skipped over. cf force and the lazyness fiasco, still broken after all those years, and people still arguing there is nothing wrong with current implementation ("but it is for lazyness" they say)

Comment: @nicolas. Why don't you take this to the R-devel list? That is where such discussions should happen. Stack overflow  is not the place.

Comment: @mnel you are probably right, I will do so later on. thank you for your hinsights.

Answer (score 8):

What is going on here?

You haven't read [The introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html), especially not the section on [Assignment within functions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Assignment-within-functions) or the section on [writing your own functions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions)

Two pertinent quotes are

> Note that any ordinary assignments done within the function are local and temporary and are lost after exit from the function.

and

> The value of the expression is the value returned for the function.

In your case the final value of your function  call is `names` which will return a character vector....

---

Scoping can be a complex issue, but your example is a simple case.

If you want a more complete reference look at the [R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html).

---

#### But `data.table` does it....

Yes, `:=` in `data.table` assigns by reference. This is not *ordinary assignment*.

`data.table` inherits from `data.frame`. They are not identical, and `:=` assigning by reference (also `setattr`) assign by reference. This goes against the standard `R` idiom.
This can also cause issues see [Why does data.table update names(DT) by reference, even if I assign to another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v)

There are other ways around it, but the standard `R` idiom is that *ordinary assignment within functions are local and temporary and are lost after exit*.

You could also consider using `ReferenceClasses`(see ?`setRefClass`)

---

It is not just limited to lists / data.frames. Atomic vectors are the same

```
  mydf <- data.frame(a=1)
  mylist <- list(a=1)
  mynumeric <- c(a = 1)

mydf <- data.frame(a=1)
mylist <- list(a=1)
mynumeric <- c(a = 1)

foo <- function(x){x[['b']] <- 1; print(names(x))}

# data.frame
foo(mydf)
# [1] "a" "b"
mydf
#    a
#  1 1

# list
foo(mylist)
# [1] "a" "b"
mylist
# $a
# [1] 1

# atomic
foo(mynumeric)
# [1] "a" "b"
 mynumeric
# a 
#  1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference. a quick .Internal(inspect(dataset)) highlight the difference between the semantic, of copied variable, and the implementation which is optimized.

Comment: But although useful and essential, that is not complete. indeed it does not seem to be enforced at **langage** level, but rely on the particular implementation of  the data frame. if you use data table, for instance, the destructive update will happen.

Comment: @nicolas -- a `data.table`  is not a `data.frame` (it inherits, but there are important differences) . There are many ways to skin a cat (locally that will skin it globally as well). The `data.table` package does this (but this can has its own issues when trying to do things programatically when in general `R` does not.)

Comment: whatever, the rule evoked is not a language property at all. it may be a wish or something people heard was good, and sometimes tried to implement. but that is not a language feature.

Comment: Your second paragraph could be removed from the answer without affecting its correctness...

Comment: You could argue that there is nothing that is "enforced at the language level" because you can call C code that can alter objects in memory.

Comment: @Dwin you mean in R, not in every language. well, then, to say that nothing is enforced at language level is a pretty useful information... !

Answer (score 3):

Here is code that accomplishes what it appears that you intended, namely the use of an anonymous function that appears to change a list argument "by-reference":

```
d <- data.frame(titi=c(0))
(function(dataset) { nam <-deparse(substitute(dataset))
   dataset[["toto"]] <- 1; assign(nam ,  dataset, envir=parent.frame() )
   print(names(dataset)) #has "toto" and "titi"
 })(d)
#[1] "titi" "toto"
 print(names(d))
#[1] "titi" "toto"
 d
#  titi toto
#1    0    1
```

I don;t think you will find that it is any easier or efficient than:

```
d <- data.frame(titi=c(0))
 addcol <- function(dataset) { 
   dataset[["toto"]] <- 1
   dataset}
d <-addcol(d)
d
#  titi toto
#1    0    1
```

Comment: of course the second is better. more functional. explicit state transition. etc..

Answer (score 3):

Doing something like

```
foo <- data.frame(x=2)
(function(df) {df[["x"]] <- 1; df})(foo)
```

without assigning the returned value to anything, and finding that `foo` is unchanged as a result, is really no different to

```
x <- 2
(function(n) {n <- 1; n})(x)
```

and finding that `x` is unchanged. Why you'd expect anything else is a good question.

---

I thought this was going to be one of the more common (and reasonable) questions about R, namely: why does modifying a dataset residing in an *outer* environment, from a *local* environment, not do anything. That is, given the following code

```
foo <- data.frame(x=2)
(function() {foo[["x"]] <- 1; foo})()
```

why is `foo` still unchanged?

In this case, it may be useful to think of

```
df[[x]] <- y
```

as syntactic sugar for

```
df <- data.frame(df[names(df)!="x"], x = y)
```

because after all, in a functional language you don't have side-effects and modifying part of an object is a side-effect. In other words, you're really making a new copy of `df` with the desired changes.

As with any assignment, this takes place in the local environment. If the original `df` also happens to reside in this environment, then the new copy will replace the old. If not, then you now have two versions of `df`: one in the local environment, and one elsewhere. If you don't assign the new version to anything, it will be lost when the function returns.