# colnames being dropped in data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table `DT2` which looks like this:

```
               custName count_ Value _By_custName Mean_ Value _By_custName Median_ Value _By_custName Min_ Value _By_custName Max_ Value _By_custName Stdev_ Value _By_custName
  1:      Aaron Edwards                         1                  1008.00                    1008.00                 1008.00                 1008.00                        NA
  2: Abigail Cunningham                         1                   754.92                     754.92                  754.92                  754.92                        NA
  3:    Abraham Mcguire                         1                   247.38                     247.38                  247.38                  247.38                        NA
  4:      Acton Mendoza                         1                   468.00                     468.00                  468.00                  468.00                        NA
  5:      Acton Ratliff                         1                   456.00                     456.00                  456.00                  456.00                        NA
 ---                                                                                                                                                                           
994:          Zia Ayala                         1                  2087.91                    2087.91                 2087.91                 2087.91                        NA
995:       Zia Mcmillan                         1                     0.00                       0.00                    0.00                    0.00                        NA
996:       Zorita Hodge                         1                  2624.50                    2624.50                 2624.50                 2624.50                        NA
997:       Zorita Petty                         1                   708.50                     708.50                  708.50                  708.50                        NA
998:     Zorita Vincent                         1                   564.00                     564.00                  564.00                  564.00                        NA
     diff_ Value _By_custName pctdiff_ Value _By_custName
  1:                      NaN                         NaN
  2:                      NaN                         NaN
  3:                      NaN                         NaN
  4:                      NaN                         NaN
  5:                      NaN                         NaN
 ---                                                     
994:                      NaN                         NaN
995:                      NaN                         NaN
996:                      NaN                         NaN
997:                      NaN                         NaN
998:                      NaN                         NaN
```

When I do:

```
cnames = colnames(as.data.frame(DT2))
```

and run the code:

```
    L = length(cnames)
for( i in 1:L){      
  .t = as.symbol(cnames[i])                          
  if(all(is.na(DT2[,eval(.t)]))){
    .del = substitute(x:=NULL, list(x=.t))
    DT2[, eval(.del)]
  } else if(any(is.na(DT2[,eval(.t)]))){
    .s0 = substitute(!is.na(x), list(x=.t))
    mu = -99       
    .s1 = substitute(is.na(x), list(x=.t))
    .s2 = substitute(x := y, list(x=.t, y=eval(mu)))
    DT2 = DT2[eval(.s1), eval(.s2)]
  }             
}
```

This works!

But when I do:

```
cnames = colnames(DT2)
```

the code breaks down with error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'NA' not found
```

Basically, the cnames vector drops terms! If I delete columns from DT2, corresponding element in cnames is dropped too. Why does this happen? Is it some pointer stuff happening in the background?

**Edit:**

Example reproduced on request:

```
> DT2 = data.table(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c(10,20,30,40,50), z = rep(NA,5), u = rep(NaN, 5), w = rep(NaN,5))
> DT2
   x  y  z   u   w
1: 1 10 NA NaN NaN
2: 2 20 NA NaN NaN
3: 3 30 NA NaN NaN
4: 4 40 NA NaN NaN
5: 5 50 NA NaN NaN
> cnames = colnames(DT2)
> L = length(cnames)
> for( i in 1:L){     
+     print("===========")
+     print(cnames) 
+     .t = as.symbol(cnames[i])                          
+     if(all(is.na(DT2[,eval(.t)]))){
+         .del = substitute(x:=NULL, list(x=.t))
+         DT2[, eval(.del)]
+     } else if(any(is.na(DT2[,eval(.t)]))){
+         .s0 = substitute(!is.na(x), list(x=.t))
+         mu = 3                              
+         .s1 = substitute(is.na(x), list(x=.t))
+         .s2 = substitute(x := y, list(x=.t, y=eval(mu)))
+         DT2 = DT2[eval(.s1), eval(.s2)]
+     } 
+     print(cnames)            
+ } 
[1] "==========="
[1] "x" "y" "z" "u" "w"
[1] "x" "y" "z" "u" "w"
[1] "==========="
[1] "x" "y" "z" "u" "w"
[1] "x" "y" "z" "u" "w"
[1] "==========="
[1] "x" "y" "z" "u" "w"
[1] "x" "y" "u" "w"
[1] "==========="
[1] "x" "y" "u" "w"
[1] "x" "y" "u"
[1] "==========="
[1] "x" "y" "u"
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'NA' not found
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a small example and small sample data?

Comment: hahahaha "magic character vector" :) Thanks @MatthewDowle! Yup. Indeed duplicate.

Comment: +1 for the great question though. I'll have a look again and see if there's anyway to catch it.

Comment: Btw, `set()` may be a better way to do dynamic `:=` than those `eval`s. But I didn't fully follow what that code is doing, so just throwing `set()` out there as an idea.

Comment: It would also be great if the details using .Internal are shared in the documentation. data.table documentation is already fantastic, and these additions will be of great help to users.

Comment: Thanks. Will check out ```set()``` too. I am just dynamically dropping columns if all values in column are ```NA```, failing which if ```NA``` exists then replacing ```NA```s with a default value of 3.

Comment: Definitely use `set()` for that then, much easier. Btw, to refer to one column by name, `DT[[colname]]` (i.e. using `[[` in base R) is faster than using data.table syntax, so that's idiomatic and recommended. People tend to forget about `[[` I guess (it doesn't copy).

Comment: Great point! Will keep that in mind. The jump from data frame syntax to data table syntax was quite a jump (with huge benefits of course!), and since this is a fairly huge code base, I have consistently used this style. Guess need to change that because speed is very important to me.

Comment: This is now documented in `v1.9.3`, in `?copy`. Please see [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md) for more info.