# data.table names character vector is a reference

Tags: r, data.table

i am encountering a strange "bug" (assuming it is not documented somewhere.) if you store the names of a data.table in a character vector, and then delete a column from the data.table, the character vector of names is automatically updated accordingly. i find this very strange and counterintuitive. Is this a bug? If not, what is the rationale for it?

EDIT: i am asking whether it isn't better to return a COPY of the current names, as opposed to a reference, which is bug-prone and is better reserved for the cases when there is a real performance benefit (such as the core data).

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.8.8  For help type: help("data.table")
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.8
> dt = data.table( a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
> cols = names(dt)
> cols
[1] "a" "b"
> dt[, a := NULL]
> cols
[1] "b"
>
```

Comment: And the question you are asking is...?

Comment: Looks more like a feature to me although I would not necessarily have expected it. Seems rather helpful that cols is "communicating" and getting updated when you erase the column.

Comment: A core principle of the data.table package is that operations are done by reference and copies avoided as much as possible. That's one reason why the package is so fast. If you think this is a bug, you haven't understood the package. I understand that this behavior can be surprising at first, but you should be careful with the word "bug".

Comment: i understand the core principles of data.table, but in my opinion having the value returned by names() be a reference is very confusing. there is no performance gain from that, and references should be reserved for when they are really needed-- the actual data.

Comment: you typed so much, but didn't explain what the meaningful performance gain is in returning a reference to the data.table names as opposed to a copy.

Comment: [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v#comment22679071_15913648) should shed some light on @Roland's point. And [here's the relevant FR](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2675&group_id=240&atid=5356) that this needs to be documented. We just haven't gotten to it yet. If you feel strongly that it should result in a copy, the best place to start a conversation is the data.table mailing list.

Comment: thanks arun. it seems to me that any performance loss from re-allocating the names vector repeatedly would be negligible given how small it is. more importantly, copying will preserve the usual R/data.frame behavior which is a good thing in the absence of a compelling reason against it. i will move this discussion to the right venue.

Answer (score 2):

You can "copy" the names of variables.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table( a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
cols = copy(names(dt))
cols
dt[, a := NULL]
cols
```

Comment: Better to copy the names than the whole table: `copy(names(dt))`

Answer (score 2):

When you defined `cols`, you are binding it to `dt`. The `:=` assignment operater is editing `dt`, and so `cols` is changed accordingly. R users don't typically deal with this issue because most code redefines the variable (rebinds it) to a new value, rather than editing the exiting object. For example, see the code below.

But, as noted by @IShouldBuyABoat, it is a feature, not a bug. Pretty typical in many languages, actually.

```
> library(data.table)
> dt = data.table( a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
> dt  
     a  b
 1:  1  1
 2:  2  2
 3:  3  3
 4:  4  4
 5:  5  5
 6:  6  6
 7:  7  7
 8:  8  8
 9:  9  9
 10: 10 10
> cols = names(dt)
> cols
[1] "a" "b"
> dt = data.table(b = 1:10)
> dt  
     b
 1:  1
 2:  2
 3:  3
 4:  4
 5:  5
 6:  6
 7:  7
 8:  8
 9:  9
 10: 10
> cols
[1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: my thoughts are that it should return a copy of the current names rather than a reference, unless there is a big performance gain for doing so (as there is for the core data). for example, if you do dim(dt) is a copy, and if you did dim.dt = dim(dt), and then deleted a column from dt, dim.dt would not be updated. this leads to inconsistencies.