# Why does setnames() affect copied tables?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create a copy of a data.table and change the name of a column in the new table. When I change the name of y$V1, the name of x$V1 also changes. Why is it so, and how do I avoid this behaviour?

Example:

```
x <- data.table(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
y <- x
setnames(y, 'V1', 'new_name')
names(y) == names(x)
```

Comment: Because it's not a copy. Have a look at `?copy`. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15913417/1191259

Comment: Please have a look at the reference semantics vignette (and other vignettes) from the package homepage on CRAN.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because R implements simple reference counting, and generally only copies on *modification* and not on assignment. So `y = x` for *any* `x` and `y` would not copy anything, and no new objects will be created.

Combined with the fact that some `data.table` functions can modify the object without copying, like `setnames`, you get the effect you see.

Use `copy` as Frank mentioned to force an explicit copy.