# R's setnames: how does it detect linked objects?

Tags: r, attributes, data.table, pass-by-reference

The `setnames` function in R (`data.table` package) is unusual for R in that it changes input by reference, meaning that it does not copy the table on which it operates.  (Not to be confused with `setNames` from the `stats` package).

This has a surprising (and inconvenient) consequence: it will change any object to which the `names` attribute was previously saved.  Viz:

```
require("data.table")

dt <- data.table(x = 1, y = 2)

dtnms <- function(dt){
    nms <- names(dt)
    print(nms)
    setnames(dt, c("a", "b"))
    nms
}
```

What would you `dtnms(dt)` to return?  `"x" "y"` of course.  Except it doesn't - `setnames` also modifies `nms` within the function, so that while `"x" "y"` is printed before `setnames`, `"a" "b"` is returned.  If you put a `stop()` before the `setnames`, you can see that `nms` is just a character vector, with no special class or other indication of its provenance.  So we would expect `setnames` to have no idea where `nms` had come from, yet somehow the link is there for `setnames` to "see".  How is this possible?  (This works the same with simple data frames).

A few further observations (remember to reset `dt` each time):

1. The link is propagated by further assignments

   ```
   dtnms2 <- function(dt){
   nms <- names(dt)
       print(nms)
       nms2 <- nms
       setnames(dt, c("a", "b"))
       nms2
   }
   ```

   `dtnms2(dt)` gives `"a" "b"`
2. The link is not just a question of similarity

   ```
   dtnms3 <- function(dt){
       chv <- c("x", "y")
       setnames(dt, c("a", "b"))
       chv
   }
   ```

   `dtnms3(dt)` gives `"x" "y"`
3. The link is not detectable by `identical`

   ```
   dtnms4 <- function(dt){
       chv <- c("x", "y")
       nms <- names(dt)
       identical(chv, nms)
   }
   ```

   `dtnms4(dt)` gives `TRUE`
4. The link can be broken (which is probably the best way round this)

   ```
   dtnms5 <- function(dt){
       nms <- names(dt)
       nms <- paste(nms)
       setnames(dt, c("a", "b"))
       nms
   }
   ```

   `dtnms5(dt)` gives `"x" "y"`, back to the expected value.  `paste` has broken the link, whatever it was.

So my question is, what is the link?  Why does `setnames` change the `nms` object, which is just a plain old character vector bearing no sign of where it came from?

Comment: Study `help("copy")`. Then research what "copy-on-modify" means.

Comment: Have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15913417/559784), read the first paragraph in`?setnames` and also read the [Reference Semantics vignette](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: TL,DR: You're suspecting `setnames` to do something it does not. The root cause is the copy on write mechanism (broadly used in many languages), `setnames` modifies the memory in place, every pointer to this space get updated as when you read them you read the same memroy space. See Arun and Roland links for details.

Comment: @Tensibai I think that Arun's link is a better duplicate.  Sorry - it is hard to check whether the question has been asked when you don't know the correct terms sometimes!

Comment: @Bazz no problem ;) I missed the link about SO post in arun comment. My bad. closing as dupe is not a problem at all, it just avoid replicating answers on multiple places. (Retracted my vote to allow a better dupe target)