# What properties of a data.table are retrieved by reference?

Tags: r, data.table

I was writing a function where I saved the names of a data.table so that I could resort it later. I found the following behaviour:

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(x=1, y=2)

nx <- names(x)
nx
# [1] "x" "y"

x[, z:=3]
nx
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
```

This came as a surprise as while I know modifying a data.table changes it by reference, I wasn't expecting the names stored in another variable to also point to it by reference! Now I know I can solve this issue by using `nx <- names(copy(x))`, but it seems that not all aspects of a `data.table` are changed by reference like this. For example:

```
x <- data.table(x=1, y=2)

cx <- ncol(x)
cx
# [1] 2

x[, z:=3]
cx
# [1] 2
```

The number of columns doesn't change by reference. Which properties do I need to be aware of when using `data.table` and which ones do I not need to worry about?

Comment: I think you have discovered a bug. I have difficulty imagining this behavior was expected.

Comment: actually I would have been surprised if `nx` hasn't change when creating variable `z`

Comment: I guess you need this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/15913417/4137985

Comment: Or this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html  (item 2 under the section on `copy()` )

Comment: @Cath Thanks, that's exactly what I needed

Comment: The difference between `ncol` and `names` is that the first one returns a result of a computation in a new variable, while the second one simply returns you an already existing variable (that's kept as an attribute in the `data.table` `x`). That + the fact that R doesn't copy on assignment + `data.table` being able to modify without copying gives you those results (as explained in the duplicates link).