# data.table setnames modifying object in calling environment

Tags: r, data.table, pass-by-reference

EDIT about possible duplicate:

The [proposed link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417) helps to understand where the issue comes from (I had posted it already as the 1st comment).
However my question is how to solve the specific issue of calling setnames in a function, not just understanding what's going on, it's not directly addressed there. Using `copy` might be an option, there might be others.

The question had 2 downvotes without comment so far, please speak up If I can improve it.

---

`data.tables::setnames` modifies values by reference, in the case below it seems to lead to unexpected behavior (unexpected for me at least).

I found an ugly way to handle it but there may be a better more systematic way to go at it, so I'd like your suggestions.

**The odd behavior**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1,b="x")
f1 <- function(df2){
  setnames(df2,"b","c")
  df2
}
f1(df1)
#   a c
# 1 1 x
df1
#   a c
# 1 1 x
```

df1 has been modified

**what if I make a copy ?**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1,b="x")
f1 <- function(df2){
 df3 <- df2
 setnames(df3,"b","c")
 df3
}
f1(df1)
#   a c
# 1 1 x
df1
#   a c
# 1 1 x
```

nope

**what if I make a copy and "pretend to change" it but don't**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1,b="x")
f1 <- function(df2){
  df3 <- subset(df2)    # note: it doesn't work with `identity`, EDIT: we can also use `data.table::copy`
  setnames(df3,"b","c")
  df3
}
f1(df1)
#   a c
# 1 1 x
df1
#   a b
# 1 1 x
```

It works

---

How should I go at it ? Is this a bug ?

---

EDIT: I found out data.table has a `copy` function that is more general and certainly more efficient than my use of `subset`

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v

Comment: I think `copy` is probably the best way to go, but maybe someone else can weigh in. The `df2` points to the same object as `df1` so when `setnames` is modifying `df2` it's really also modifying `df1` (because the point of `setnames` is to not make a copy of the object you're modifying). Try `library(pryr); address(df1);
  f_address <- function(df2) print(address(df2));
  f_address(df1)`

Comment: More test code in case you're interested - `x<-1; y <- x
  address(x); address(y)`.  Using `setattr(x,"test",TRUE)` both `x` and `y` will be changed because `setattr` is specifically designed to not make a copy. However, using a base R approach with something like: `attributes(y) <- list("Attr2" = FALSE)` we see that `y` and `x` now differ and checking the `address`es they point to different objects.

Comment: It's so easy to let a mistake slip though... Ideally it'd be nice to be able to "secure" the use of `setnames`. Else I may just drop it, I don't care much about the fact it passes by reference but I like the syntax using `old` and `new`.

Comment: Could you define a new function that makes a copy for you? E.g. `setnames_copy <- function(x, old, new){
    y <- copy(x);
    setnames(y, old, new)
  }`

Comment: That's a good idea, maybe I'd overload SetName for it to work like setnames, except it returns the copy. I also found about `dplyr::rename` which is a good solution

Comment: Cool, just put this as an answer for future readers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does data.table update names(DT) by reference, even if I assign to another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the expected behavior since `df2` points to the same object as `df1`. You can see this with:

```
library(pryr)
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(a=1,b="x")
address(df1)
#[1] "0000000002892318" (will be different for others)

f_address<-function(df2) print(address(df2))
f_address(df1)
#[1] "0000000002892318"
```

Since `setnames` changes the inputs by reference, when it is changing `df2` it is changing the object that both `df1` and `df2` point to.

To change this, you could create your own function that explicitly copies `df1` and then modifies it:

```
setnames_copy <- function(x, old, new){ 
  y <- copy(x)
  setnames(y, old, new) 
}

f2 <- function(df2){
  setnames_copy(df2, "b", "c")
}
df3 <- f2(df1)
df3
#  a c
#1 1 x

df1
#  a b
#1 1 x
```

As you can see, `df1` is left unmodified.

Comment: I built on your proposal to write a hacky function that behaves more like setnames, see my answer

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper cool! Interesting approach - fyi, not my downvote

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @mike-h 's solution, here's a function that behaves like setnames except it creates a copy if you're using setnames outside of the environment where your input was defined.

```
library(pryr)
setnames2 <- function(`$$`,old,new,verbose = FALSE){
  var_name <- as.character(substitute(`$$`))
  calling_env_objects  <- sapply(ls(envir=parent.frame(n=2)),. %>% get(envir=parent.frame(n=2)) %>% address)
  copied_object <- calling_env_objects[calling_env_objects == address(`$$`)]
  if(length(copied_object) ==0){          # if the address isn't used in the calling environment's calling environment
    if(verbose){cat("use regular setnames\n")}
    setnames(`$$`,old,new)
  } else if (length(copied_object) ==1){  # if the address is already in use in the calling environment's calling environment
    if(verbose){cat("create copy then use setnames on it and assign to relevant environment\n")}
    y <- copy(`$$`);setnames(y, old, new);assign(var_name,y,envir=parent.frame())
  } else {print("you shouldn't go around naming objects `$$`...")}
}

df1 <- data.frame(a=1,b="x")
f3 <- function(df2){
  setnames2(df2,"b","c",verbose=TRUE)
  print(df2)
}
f3(df1)
# create copy then use setnames on it and assign to relevant environment
#   a c
# 1 1 x
df1
#   a b
# 1 1 x    

f4 <- function(df2){
  df2 <- copy(df2)
  setnames2(df2,"b","c",verbose=TRUE)
  print(df2)
}
f4(df1)
# use regular setnames
#   a c
# 1 1 x
df1
#   a b
# 1 1 x
```