# Data.table set function not dropping columns

Tags: r, data.table

I tried dropping columns from a data.table using the `set` function, but found that not all columns were dropped, yet no warnings or errors were reported.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(iris)
drop.vars <- names(dt)[1:3]

for (colName in names(dt)) {
  if (colName %in% drop.vars)
    set(dt, j = colName, value = NULL)
}

any(names(dt) %in% drop.vars)
```

I expected `any` to return FALSE, but it actually returns TRUE.  If I run the loop multiple times, it drops all the columns in `drop.vars` after 2-3 runs (depending on the size of the original data.table).

I eventually ended up using a different formulation

```
    set(dt, j = which(colName %in% drop.vars), value = NULL)
```

, which dropped the columns as expected.  However, can someone explain why using set inside of a `for` loop doesn't work as expected?

This was tested on R 3.4.0 with data.table 1.10.4 as well as on MRO 3.4.0 with the development version of 1.10.5.

Comment: I'm guessing it's thanks to this quirk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v#comment22679071_15913648

Comment: Wrapping `names` in `copy` when writing the `for` loop gives the expected behavior.

Comment: Ok, I'll close the question linking to that one then.