# Rearranging columns in data table affecting other variables in R

Tags: r, debugging, data.table, rstudio

I have the following lines of code which attempts to shuffle columns of a data table and rename them.

```
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
cat('\14')
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
DF<-matrix(nrow = 10,ncol=5)
DF<-data.frame(DF)
colnames(DF)<-c(1,2,3,4,5)

DF.Old <- DF
DFID <- DF$`1`
DF$`1` <- NULL

Int.Vals <- colnames(DF)
print(Int.Vals)

Jumble.Int.Vals <- sample(colnames(DF))
DF <- setcolorder(DF,Jumble.Int.Vals)
print(Int.Vals)
```

When executed this all together from a script file (CTRL+SHIFT+S), the variable `Int.Vals` which was `{2,3,4,5}` and untouched by the last three lines, becomes shuffled like `{5,4,3,2}`. This only happens when I execute the lines togather and doesn't happen if I execute the script line by line where `Int.Vals` is unchanged.

I find this logically inconsistent. Can anybody point out, why this is happening?

Comment: It appears that `colnames` function (and also `names` function) are returning a reference to the dataframe names, rather than a character vector which is the expected behavior... if you really want to avoid it, try `Int.Vals <- copy(colnames(DF))`  I can't find in the documentation or source yet a full explanation

Comment: For more info re J Win's point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v