# R function to failback in a left_join?

Tags: r

I have more than 20 different datatables with data indexed by the same coding system (North American Industry Classification System, NAICS) that I want to join into one table.

The problem is that there are different levels of detail available in each table and when I join I want to find the best match by failing up the coding system's hierarchy until a match is found.

A regular `left_join` won't work because there won't always be exact matches. I have had a look at the `fuzzyjoin` package, but it is a little over my head.

I want to start with a table of codes:

```
t_master
# A tibble: 360 x 1
   NAICS17
   <chr>  
 1 311111 
 2 311119 
 3 311211 
 4 311212 
 5 311213 
 6 311221 
 7 311224 
 8 311225 
 9 311230 
10 311313 
# ... with 350 more rows

t_master <- structure(list(NAICS17 = c(311111L, 311119L, 311211L, 311212L, 
311213L, 311221L, 311224L, 311225L, 311230L, 311313L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

and then cycle through all of the other tables finding the best available match in each and then join all of the variables. Sometimes that is simple because there is an exact match (311111 and 311119 from t_asm would be joined to 311111 and 311119 in t_master):

```
t_asm
# A tibble: 8,167 x 3
   NAICS17 CEXBLD   CEXMCH  
   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   
 1 31-33   16806796 96986337
 2 311     2099542  9063451 
 3 3111    92429    517196  
 4 31111   92429    517196  
 5 311111  49756    225494  
 6 311119  42673    291702  
 7 3112    192911   1016770 
 8 31121   75310    267693  
 9 31121M  75310    267693  
10 31122   94339    546407  
# ... with 8,157 more rows

t_asm <- structure(list(NAICS17 = c("31-33", "311", "3111", "31111", "311111", 
"311119", "3112", "31121", "31121M", "31122"), CEXBLD = c("16806796", 
"2099542", "92429", "92429", "49756", "42673", "192911", "75310", 
"75310", "94339"), CEXMCH = c("96986337", "9063451", "517196", 
"517196", "225494", "291702", "1016770", "267693", "267693", 
"546407")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

But sometimes I want it to look for the best match, even if that is less detailed (311 from t_brdis_2015 would be joined to both 311111 and 311119 in t_master)

```
t_brdis_2015
# A tibble: 90 x 3
   NAICS17 rdcost_total rdcost_wage
   <chr>   <chr>        <chr>      
 1 0       355821       204170     
 2 31      236132       129375     
 3 32      236132       129375     
 4 33      236132       129375     
 5 311     4838         2945       
 6 312     1002         532        
 7 313     748          481        
 8 314     748          481        
 9 315     748          481        
10 316     748          481        
# ... with 80 more rows

t_brdis_2015 <- structure(list(NAICS17 = c("0", "31", "32", "33", "311", "312", 
"313", "314", "315", "316"), rdcost_total = c("355821", "236132", 
"236132", "236132", "4838", "1002", "748", "748", "748", "748"
), rdcost_wage = c("204170", "129375", "129375", "129375", "2945", 
"532", "481", "481", "481", "481")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

It would be a left join, I want all of t_master's observations to be joined with just one observation from the other datatables.

The method of failing back would be (using 311111 as an example):

- Try 311111
- Try 31111
- Try 3111
- Try 311
- Try 31
- Try 3
- Return an NA

Thanks and let me know if any of that isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. You are exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a sequence of update joins:

```
library(data.table)

ncs  = seq_len(max(nchar(t_master$NAICS17)))
nms  = copy(names(t_asm))
xnms = sprintf("x.%s", nms)
tnms = replace(nms, nms == "NAICS17", "m")

t_asm2 <- data.table(t_asm)
out = data.table(t_master)
out[, NAICS17 := as.character(NAICS17)]
out[, m := NA_character_]
for (nc in rev(ncs)){
  out[is.na(m), target := substr(NAICS17, 1, nc)]
  out[is.na(m), 
    (tnms) := t_asm2[.SD, on=.(NAICS17 = target), mget(xnms)][]
  ]
  if (!anyNA(out$m)) break
}
out[, target := NULL][]

    NAICS17      m  CEXBLD  CEXMCH
 1:  311111 311111   49756  225494
 2:  311119 311119   42673  291702
 3:  311211  31121   75310  267693
 4:  311212  31121   75310  267693
 5:  311213  31121   75310  267693
 6:  311221  31122   94339  546407
 7:  311224  31122   94339  546407
 8:  311225  31122   94339  546407
 9:  311230   3112  192911 1016770
10:  311313    311 2099542 9063451
```

`m` is the value that was matched; `target` is the value we're trying to match in the current iteration of the loop. The iterations work backwards, starting from the longest code. (Look at `rev(ncs)` which is being iterated over.)

By filtering to `is.na(m)`, we're skipping rows that have been matched in earlier iterations. The test `anyNA(out$m)` allows us to quit early if every row is matched.

`copy` is just a measure to avoid problems noted in [Why does data.table update names(DT) by reference, even if I assign to another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15913417)

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Just so I understand, the loop basically throws an na in to start and then gradually builds up the code to more and more detail to see if it can improve upon that?

Sorry, it took me this long to work through line by line what was going on.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I run it:

Error in `[.tbl_df`(t_asm, .SD, on = list(NAICS17 = target), mget(xnms)) : 
  unused argument (on = list(NAICS17 = target))

Thoughts?

Comment: @Paul Oh, I forgot to convert it to a data.table. I've edited to use `t_asm2 <- data.table(t_asm)` above. Re understanding the code, yes, but it cuts down the code from a max length of 6 rather than building it up. You can see it iterates over `rev(ncs)` (I had a typo in constructing ncs, fixed just now.)

Comment: That did it, thanks so much! You saved me a bunch of time

Comment: I have been messing with this a bit and have made it work for some of my needs. But I realized after the fact that a consideration of my data that I didn't include is that there may be multiple matches because some of the data is time series data. So I am getting this error "Supplied 4 items to be assigned to 360 items of column 'match' " (can supply additional info or ask a separate question if necessary)

Comment: @Paul Hm, sounds better as a separate question since I don't quite follow the extension, and other folks might have some different ideas about how to address it.