# colnames() behaviour with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

Using colnames() function with a data.table seems to convert the resulting variable to a "passed by reference" one. I'm using R 3.6.0 and data.table 1.12.2

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(
  ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
  a = 1:6,
  b = 7:12,
  c = 13:18
)

column_names = colnames(DT)
DT[, e := 23:28]
column_names
```

I expected column_names to be "ID" "a" "b" and "c" not including the newly added column "e". However column_names has been updated. Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does data.table update names(DT) by reference, even if I assign to another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v)

Comment: yes, it's correct behavior.

Answer (score 3):

We need to use `copy` to avoid it getting changed after the assignment based on the documentation of `?copy`

> A copy() may be required when doing dt_names = names(DT). Due to R's copy-on-modify, dt_names still points to the same location in memory as names(DT). Therefore modifying DT by reference now, say by adding a new column, dt_names will also get updated. To avoid this, one has to explicitly copy: dt_names <- copy(names(DT))

So, we do

```
column_names = copy(colnames(DT))
```

Now, after the assignment

```
DT[, e := 23:28]
column_names 
#[1] "ID" "a"  "b"  "c"
```