# R hanging on names(dt) <- c(a,b,c) assignment but only inside a function ...?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm pretty experienced with R but for the life of me I can't figure this out. I know you are supposed to include a reproducible example but I tried my hardest and couldn't reproduce the error outside of where I encountered it, which is inside a very long function in the middle of lengthy data processing script.

When I run this script, it hangs permanently (no error, just frozen) at the exact point I assign new column names to a `data.table` like so:

```
func <- function(args){
# lots of stuff
names(dt) <- c('a','b','c')
# lots more stuff
}
```

R hangs at exactly this point, every time. But it ONLY does it when that line is run inside the function. I can execute the code in the global environment no problem. And, if I use `setnames(dt, c('a','b','c'))` instead (inside the function), it fixes it.

Even more strangely, it only recently started doing it. Exactly the same script has been running from start to finish for months on a daily basis with no issues. Has anyone encountered anything similar?

Comment: It's hard to say without a reproducible example. Perhaps, you are trying to modify some other object without knowing and it crashes it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v) for perhaps a related issue.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg. After going through that I'm wondering if it's something to do with Google Drive (where the script is located) syncing and somehow modifying the memory location of the referenced object. Although that doesn't explain why it only happens inside a function...

Comment: I think David's got the right of it. Because memory is shared, it may be hard to predict what happens if you're using `names<-`, which will also edit (and possibly copy) any other object sharing that memory (`names<-.data.table` _does_ do a shallow copy...). You should use `setnames`. If you're able to make a reproducible example, please file an issue and we'll see if there's any unexpected behavior.