# R data.table 'variable <- names(DT)': variable gets overwritten with := operator

Tags: r, reference, data.table

I have a very simple code that reproduces my issue in R (and data.table package):

If I save the column names into a variable without copy(), it gets overwritten when using the `:=` operator **later** on in the code:

```
input_table = data.table(A = 1:3, B = 2:4)
some_value    = 0.025

original_colnames <- names(input_table)
original_colnames_copy <- copy(names(input_table))

identical(original_colnames, c("A", "B"))      # returns TRUE

# create a new column
input_table[, C   :=      A + some_value]

identical(original_colnames, c("A", "B"))      # returns FALSE, original_colnames contains "C" as well
identical(original_colnames_copy, c("A", "B")) # returns TRUE
```

This problem does not persist if I use the following code to create the new column:

```
input_table = mutate(input_table, C= A + some_value)
```

Is this intended (am I missing some deeper knowledge in R / data.table)?

R.version is 4.1.0, data.table version is 1.14.0.

Comment: I believe `original_colnames` is effectively (for simplicity and efficiency) a pointer to the in-memory attributes of the frame, directly returning the column names without copying it into a new variable. While R's typical pass-by-value semantics would lead one to believe that `names(.)` extracts the names at the time of call and copies them into a new vector, this is not true. Since `data.table` is working by reference, it adds a column name to the same attribute location in memory, so `original_colnames` immediately reflects the difference.

Comment: Yes, it is intended. It can't be avoided without having worse performance.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware that `data.table` is working by reference, but I was not aware that there are similar ways in `base` as well

Comment: I thought I had seen an FAQ about this. There's a related issue ([rdatatable/data.table#3847](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3847)), though its links don't talk specifically about `colnames(.)`'s interactions here. I think *"similar ways in `base`"* may be a little misleading, since assigning to `original_colnames` has no effect on the frame, and if you were to do this with a `data.frame` instead, the premise for `original_colnames`'s referencing will still be the same but you will not see the same behavior, since adding a column is not done in-place (so the link is broken).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v#comment22679071_15913648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by the comments below the question:
[Why does data.table update names(DT) by reference, even if I assign to another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913417/why-does-data-table-update-namesdt-by-reference-even-if-i-assign-to-another-v#comment22679071_15913648)

Comment: You should copy that comment here and not just refer to it